# Check if a Scala / Akka actor is terminated

Tags: scala, akka, actor

While executing code within one actor, I need to check if the actor is still alive.
Would this be advisable or is there a better way?

```
if (self != akka.actor.DeadLetter) {
  // do something
}
```

Thanks!

EDIT---

Thanks for all your inputs. What happens is the following. I am using Play. As my actor starts, upon an incoming request, a timeout is scheduled.

```
Promise.timeout({
     Logger.info(s"$self, timeout expired")
     // do something
}, timeoutValue)
```

Sometimes the actor is stopped for other reasons before the timeout expires (for instance, the client disconnects). In that case, what I see then in the logs is

```
Actor[akka://application/deadLetters], timeout expired.
```

To my understanding, this means that the default `deadLetters` actor is executing that code. So my question really is: what is the best way to check if the Promise code is executed after the actor is terminated, and prevent it from going further if that is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your actor is dead, no code within the actor will be running.

You can check if specific actor is available, with [actorSelection](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3.3/index.html#akka.actor.ActorSelection), and then send a message to whatever is returned as a result (if there will be nothing, no message will be sent).

```
ActorContext.actorSelection(<your-actor-name>) ! someMessage
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you give a look at my question edits? It explains better the issue, taken into account your remark about code in dead actors.

Comment: Hi Fabio :) You could try to do something with postStop for that actor, as the other author suggested (this is the method which should be called when the actor terminates). For example, send a message to another (watching) actor, which would change the context? Or use some other external synchronization.

Answer (score 4):

You should familiarize yourself with the actor lifecycle: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.4/scala/actors.html#Actor_Lifecycle

From inside an actor you can implement the postStop() callback that will be called immediately before your actor is going to be stopped. If you want to monitor the lifecycle of the actor from another actor you should use DeathWatch: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.4/scala/actors.html#Lifecycle_Monitoring_aka_DeathWatch

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The code is indeed executed in the DeadLetter actor. I edited the question to give more context.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can watch your actor and if you receive message `Terminated` you are sure that your actor is not running.

```
ActorContext.watch(self)
```

Comment: The way I could use this information then would be to set some state in the actor and check such state in my if statement. The if statement will be executed anyway at some point (it's in a Play Promise timeout). I'd rather use a cleaner way if there's any.

Comment: While watch is the preferred way to get notified when an actor has been stopped it does not help detecting the fact of stopping from inside the actor.

Comment: Could you explain what exactly is a `ActorContext`? Thanks

Comment: @WeiLin: A variable of type ActorContext and name "context" is available inside every actor. So you can always define context.watch(someActorRef) where "someActorRef" is an instance of type ActorRef to monitor some other actor. If this particular actor dies a Terminated message with the corresponding ActorRef is returned (catch it in the receive block with `case Terminated(actorRef) => ...`